# Bash script to remove last three charater in a file name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

For ex the file is this:

```
NBDG6_CDRCCN_4004_-TTNBDG6_CCN_51-140108-1433-802580.00.Blk32768Blk.CCN:00
```

I want to rename this file to:

```
NBDG6_CDRCCN_4004_-TTNBDG6_CCN_51-140108-1433-802580.00.Blk32768Blk.CCN
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 1):

Using `${parameter%word}` (Remove matching suffix pattern):

```
$ echo "$fn"
NBDG6_CDRCCN_4004_-TTNBDG6_CCN_51-140108-1433-802580.00.Blk32768Blk.CCN:00
$ echo "${fn%:*}"
NBDG6_CDRCCN_4004_-TTNBDG6_CCN_51-140108-1433-802580.00.Blk32768Blk.CCN
```

Answer (score 0):

Using cut

```
$ echo $fn
NBDG6_CDRCCN_4004_-TTNBDG6_CCN_51-140108-1433-802580.00.Blk32768Blk.CCN:00

$ echo $fn |cut -d: -f1
NBDG6_CDRCCN_4004_-TTNBDG6_CCN_51-140108-1433-802580.00.Blk32768Blk.CCN
```

Using awk

```
echo $fn |awk -F : '{print $1}'
```

more ways...

Answer (score 0):

According to the link [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/search/label/rename):
This should work:

```
awk '{old=$0;gsub(/...$/,"",$0);system("mv \""old"\" "$0)}'
```

provided the file name is given as input.
For eg:

```
ls -1 NBDG6_CDRCCN_4004_-TTNBDG6_CCN_51-140108-1433-802580.00.Blk32768Blk.CCN:00|nawk '{old=$0;gsub(/...$/,"",$0);system("mv \""old"\" "$0)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename file using [bash string manipulations](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
# Filename needs to be in a variable
file=NBDG6_CDRCCN_4004_-TTNBDG6_CCN_51-140108-1433-802580.00.Blk32768Blk.CCN:00

# Rename file
mv "$file" "${file%???}"
```

This removes the last three characters from filename.

Answer (score 0):

Using just bash:

```
fn='NBDG6_CDRCCN_4004_-TTNBDG6_CCN_51-140108-1433-802580.00.Blk32768Blk.CCN:00'
mv "$fn" "${fn::-3}"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have Ruby

```
echo NBDG6_CD* | ruby -e 'f=gets.chomp;File.rename(f, f[0..-4])'
```